# Using AWK to deliminate columns by REGEX

Tags: unix, awk, sed

Sorry if this question is easily answered but I've tried a several different ways on how to make it work with no avail at this point.

I have to use AWK for a class project and have a large text file containing all the countries in the world with their GDPs by year. It looks something like this:

```
CountryYearGDP
```

I'd like it to look something more like:

```
Country Year GDP
```

However because some of the countries have long names and white-space acts as a delimiter, data columns $1, $2, $3 might contain everything I'm looking for on some entries, But on others $1, $2, $3 might still be the name of the country and the GDP in $7.

So my question is this, what would be the best way to ensure the full name of a country is strictly in $1.

Sorry if the question is pretty basic, but I just can't get it to format right. Thanks for any help or tips.

Comment: Please, post a few lines  of sample data. Edit the data to the original question, prepend with 4 spaces. Do not post it as a comment.

Comment: Have a look at the `sub` command

Answer (score 0):

A few assumptions about your data;

- Country names never contain digits
- Years are expressed as four consecutive digits
- GDP is expressed as anything but a newline

Using sed you could clean it up as follows:

```
$ cat sample.txt
United States of America201216.36 trillion US dollars
France20142.852 trillion US dollars 
Sierra Leone20134.92 billion US dollars
Norway2015386.7 billion US dollars
$ tab=$(echo -e "\t")
$ sed "s/\([^0-9]*\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)\(.*\)/\1${tab}\2${tab}\3/" sample.txt
United States of America    2012    16.36 trillion US dollars
France  2014    2.852 trillion US dollars 
Sierra Leone    2013    4.92 billion US dollars
Norway  2015    386.7 billion US dollars
$
```

- The "s/from/to/" command matches and replaces.
- Backslash parenthesis "\(\)" starts or ends a group.
- Square brackets "[]" surround a set of characters.
- The caret "^" negates such a set of characters.
- Asterisk "*" matches zero or more occurences.
- Backslash curly brace "\{n\}" modifies the previous expression to demand a certain number of occurences.
- Dot "." matches anything that's not a newline.
- Dollar followed by curly braces grabs the value of a variable from the shell.

If you **have to** use awk and awk only for the solution, it's a bit harder - especially if the awk version is old.

Added:

```
$  awk --version | head -1
GNU Awk 4.2.0, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.6, GNU MP 6.1.2)
$ awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {match($0,/([^0-9]*)([0-9]{4})(.*)/,m); \
print m[1], m[2], m[3]}' sample.txt
United States of America    2012    16.36 trillion US dollars
France  2014    2.852 trillion US dollars 
Sierra Leone    2013    4.92 billion US dollars
Norway  2015    386.7 billion US dollars
```

OFS is the output field separator.
The match(what,how,whereto) function looks at the entire input record ($0), matches in groups similar to those in the sed example above, and stores the matching groups in the array m.